# Is $f$ continuous on $[0,1]$ if $f(x)=0\ \forall x \in (0,1]$ and $f(0)=10$

Tags: real-analysis

Is $f$ continuous on $[0,1]$ if $f(x)=0\ \forall x \in (0,1]$ and $f(0)=10.$

I don't think it is because for $|x-0|< \delta$ and $x \in a $ $|f(x)-f(0)|=|f(x)-10|$ but since $x \in a$ we have $|f(x)-10|=|0-10|=|10|$ which is not less all real $> 0$.

Also in this case is $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \,dx = 0.$ Essentially we just ignore the $10$?

Comment: first, if you want to show that a function is not continuous at a point, write out the definition of continuity precisely and the negate it. that will give u a precise definition of what it means to be not continuous at a point. second, it can be shown using darboux sums or something of the like that if a function differs from another integrable function by finitely many points, then their integrals have the same value.

Comment: Got it. Just to be sure though, f would not be continuous on [0,1] right? Since if $\epsilon =5$ then no $\delta >0$ would make it so that $|f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$ when $|x|<\delta$

Comment: that’s exactly right